# using wildcards for projectCP in evosuite test case generation

Tags: java, ubuntu, ant, code-generation, evosuite

I use evosuite 1.0.1 for automated test case generation for several open source projects. I use java 1.8 on a unix platform (ubuntu 14.04).

Is there a way to use wildcards for dependencies in the -projectCP tag?

Some of my projects depend on a huge number of libraries and this could save me heaps of time. If you have a solution for either terminal or ant build script (no IDE) I would be very thankful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is (currently) not possible to use wildcards in `-projectCP`. A workaround is to use first the `-setup` option to create the classpath (in which using wildcards is possible) on a configuration file on disk, and then run EvoSuite without `-projectCP` (as the CP will be taken by the previously generated file). For more info, look at the documentation on http://www.evosuite.org/documentation/commandline/